# Understanding Asp.net Core Dependency Injection when registering multiple implementations of Mediatr IPipelineBehavior

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection, mediatr

I saw the following code using Asp.Net Core 3.1 with Mediatr using IPipelineBehavior.

[Startup](https://github.com/jasontaylordev/CleanArchitecture/blob/master/src/Application/DependencyInjection.cs)

```cs
services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(RequestPerformanceBehaviour<,>));
services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(RequestValidationBehavior<,>));
services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(UnhandledExceptionBehaviour<,>));
```

[RequestValidationBehavior](https://github.com/jasontaylordev/CleanArchitecture/blob/master/src/Application/Common/Behaviours/ValidationBehavior.cs)

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using FluentValidation;
using MediatR;
using ValidationException = CleanArchitecture.Application.Common.Exceptions.ValidationException;

public class RequestValidationBehavior<TRequest, TResponse> : IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>
    where TRequest : IRequest<TResponse>
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IValidator<TRequest>> _validators;

    public RequestValidationBehavior(IEnumerable<IValidator<TRequest>> validators)
    {
        _validators = validators;
    }

    public Task<TResponse> Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate<TResponse> next)
    {
        if (_validators.Any())
        {
            var context = new ValidationContext(request);

            var failures = _validators
                .Select(v => v.Validate(context))
                .SelectMany(result => result.Errors)
                .Where(f => f != null)
                .ToList();

            if (failures.Count != 0)
            {
                throw new ValidationException(failures);
            }
        }

        return next();
    }
}
```

However, Based on my limited understanding of asp.net DI, shouldn't `_validators` be of type `IValidator<TRequest>`? Why is it of type `IEnumerable<IValidator<TRequest>>`?

When running the code, `_validators` is always of length = 1.

Where can I find more documentation on when the DI will resolve an implementation to IEnumerable?

## Update

Thanks to [Deepak Mishra](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61359557/5431968) and [Steven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61358421/understanding-asp-net-core-dependency-injection-when-registering-multiple-implem/61359557#comment108547269_61358421) for helping me understand. I learned that this is how dotnet DI resolve multiple implementations of the same interface. To get all implementations, I'd use `IEnumerable<Interface>` to get all services that implement it. Here is a working example demoing this:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace DotnetCoreDependencyInjection
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
            services.AddSingleton<IValidator<Shipment>, ValidateSourceAddress>();
            services.AddSingleton<IValidator<Shipment>, ValidateDestinationAddress>();

            var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

            using var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope();

            // DI will resolve IEnumerable<IValidator<Shipment>> to all implementations of IValidator<Shipment>
            var validators = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IEnumerable<IValidator<Shipment>>>();

            foreach (var validator in validators)
            {
                validator.Validate(new Shipment{ SourceAddress = "Source Address", DestinationAddress = "Destination Address"});
            }

        }
    }

    class Shipment
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string DestinationAddress { get; set; }
        public string SourceAddress { get; set; }
    }

    interface IValidator<T>
    {
        void Validate(T shipment);
    }

    class ValidateSourceAddress : IValidator<Shipment>
    {
        public void Validate(Shipment shipment)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Validate SourceAddress: {shipment.SourceAddress}");
        }
    }

    class ValidateDestinationAddress : IValidator<Shipment>
    {
        public void Validate(Shipment shipment)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Validate DestinationAddress: {shipment.DestinationAddress}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The injection of an `IEnumerable<Validator<T>>` implies that you can implement multiple `IValidator<T>` classes for the same `T`. Say for instance that `T` is an `ShipOrder`. You could have `OrderShouldNotbeShipped` and `OrderShouldBePayed` classes that both implement `IValidator<ShipOrder>`.

Answer (score 1):

When you register multiple implementation of the same interface, the DI can resolve with the IEnumerable containing all the implementation. If you don't specify IEnumerable, then it will contain only first implementation.